# ImportError: cannot import name Flask in app engine

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I am trying to deploy a sample flask example using this [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/python-standard-env) in google app engine.When I try to run it using **dev_appserver.py** in local, it works fine.But after deploying it google cloud,it keeps showing me import flask error.

Went through all stackoverflow solutions, but nothing worked.
Please tell me what I am doing wrong

***main.py***

```html
# [START app]
import logging
import sys
from os.path import expanduser, os, dirname


from flask import Flask, render_template, request

user_home = expanduser("~")
sys.path.append(user_home + 'flask/lib')

app = Flask(__name__)



# [START form]
@app.route('/form')
def form():
    return render_template('form.html')
# [END form]


# [START submitted]
@app.route('/submitted', methods=['POST'])
def submitted_form():
    name = request.form['name']
    email = request.form['email']
    site = request.form['site_url']
    comments = request.form['comments']

    # [END submitted]
    # [START render_template]
    return render_template(
        'submitted_form.html',
        name=name,
        email=email,
        site=site,
        comments=comments)
    # [END render_template]


@app.errorhandler(500)
def server_error(e):
    # Log the error and stacktrace.
    logging.exception('An error occurred during a request.')
    return 'An internal error occurred.', 500
```

***app.yaml***

```html
runtime: python27
api_version: 1

threadsafe: true
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main.app


# [START handlers]
handlers:

- url: /.*
  script: main.app
# [END handlers]
```

Answer (score 4):

To use Flask in the App Engine Standard Environment, you need to vendor it using a **lib** folder and an **appengine_config.py** file.  It's not (yet) packaged as a built-in library, so you can't just declare it in the **libraries** section of app.yaml.

For all the detail, see the [Setting up libraries to enable development](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/python-standard-env#setting_up_libraries_to_enable_development) section in the Getting Started doc, but here's the minimal version:

First make a **lib** folder in the root of your application (the folder containing app.yaml) and install Flask and its dependencies there using pip:

```
mkdir lib
pip install -t lib flask
```

Now create a file called **appengine_config.py** in the same folder, containing the following:

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor
vendor.add('lib')
```

Once you deploy the app, including **appengine_config.py** and the **lib** folder, you should be able to import flask as usual.

Comment: tried the same,still getting the same error.
I created a file name requirements.txt ,entered all the libraries needed in the file and used pip install -t lib -r requirements.txt to install the dependencies

Comment: Did you also create appengine_config.py?  If you don't do that, you won't be able to import files from the 'lib' folder.

Comment: I find this solution somewhere,apparently now its working fine


`on_appengine = os.environ.get('SERVER_SOFTWARE','').startswith('Development')
if on_appengine and os.name == 'nt':
    sys.platform = "Not Windows"`

Comment: I'm puzzled as to how adding that code would help with an ImportError.  All that does is change sys.platform when you're running under dev_appserver.py on Windows...

Comment: Google now (March 2021) says Flask is included with the runtime.  I am getting the same error for some reason in an app that was OK a month ago. I know it's time to migrate from 2 to 3. 
 https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27

Answer (score 1):

Please try if it helps to add to your app.yaml the flask dependency

```
libraries:
- name: flask
  version: latest
```

Comment: its giving me following error while deploying:
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) An error occurred while parsing file
the library "flask" is not supported

Answer (score 0):

Check whether there is a file named `flask.py` at the same folder. If found, rename it to another name.

Comment: I checked, there is no file named file named flask.py in the folder.

Comment: I'm sorry that I don't know why now. Maybe you can make a virtualenv, and then try it again.

Comment: I have created a virtualenv for flask as per instruction mentioned in google app engine docs.
That's where I am stuck cuz nowhere its mentioned how to resolve it